# How to scrape TMDB using Ruby? Getting undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass error

Tags: ruby, api

I've got a list of movies and I'm trying to scrape TheMovieDatabase.org (TMDB) to return each of the movie's ID (just an example, I plan to retrieve more info, but my code is failing at this point).

I'm using the gem themoviedb (https://github.com/ahmetabdi/themoviedb), and I've got an array of IMDB movie IDs (around 10,000 movies), which I'm iterating through and performing a API call on each of them, like this:

```
imdb_id = ["tt0114709", "tt0113497", "tt0107050", "tt0114885", "tt0113041", "tt0113277" (etc...)]

imdb_id.each do |id|
    result = Tmdb::Find.imdb_id(id)
    p result['movie_results'][0]["id"]
end
```

However, the code fails after a number of iterations with this error:

```
`block in <main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Sometimes it will fail on the 40th ID (most common), or the 88th ID, or the 109th. There is nothing different between these IDs and any other ID which success in the array, and if I query them alone it works fine:

```
result = Tmdb::Find.imdb_id(imdb_id[41])
p result['movie_results'][0]["id"]
```

The JSON result for `Tmdb::Find.imdb_id(imdb_id[41])` look like this (I removed some data that I'm not using for readability):

```
{  
   "movie_results"   =>   [  
      {  
         "adult"         =>false,
         "id"         =>11443
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm really confused what's causing the problem. Should I have some delay between API calls? Is this even the best way to perform lots of API calls in Ruby?

**EDIT**

found this error in the JSON: `"status_message"=>"Your request count (41) is over the allowed limit of 40."}`. I need to implement a throttle in my code...

Comment: If anyone is still looking for a workaround for this. Making the script sleep for *6* seconds every 40 requests still works. As shown here : https://github.com/o19s/relevant-search-book/issues/1

Answer (score 1):

When you access a property through multiple levels you *assume* they're all present and will suffer an error when they're not. This snippet, for example:

```
result['movie_results'][0]["id"]
```

If `result['movie_results']` is not an array, or if it is an array but is empty, or is something other than a Hash, this will explode with an exception.

The safer approach is this:

```
result['movie_results'] && result['movie_results'][0] && result['movie_results'][0]["id"]
```

That's awfully annoying to do on a frequent basis, so you might want to write a method that carefully [digs down](https://blog.blockscore.com/new-features-in-ruby-2-3/) to the value you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I'll implement this. Can you check my edit? It looks like I will have to implement a 10s throttle every 40 requests. Is using sleep() and a while loop a good solution? Seems really archaic to me.

Comment: Ruby 2.3.0 introduces a "save navigation" operator for this specific issue http://aaronlasseigne.com/2016/01/04/rubys-new-safe-navigation-not-equal-operator/